# How to implement neural style transfer?

Tags: neural-networks

In the paper [A Neural Algorithm of Artistic Style](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576v2.pdf), Leon A. Gatys et all. describe a process of extracting the content and style vectors from an image separately. They use this technique to generate new images that have the content from one image and style from another, it's called **neural style transfer** here's what it looks like:

[image]

Are there any existing implementations for version 11 of Mathematica?

**Links:**

- There is a partial nonworking description [on the wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/885941?_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.wolfram.com%2Fgroups%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_groupId%3D0%26_3_keywords%3Dstyle%2Btransfer%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch%26_3_redirect%3D%252Fweb%252Fcommunity%252Fgroups%252F-%252Fm%252Ft%252F885941).
- Another [helpful paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.08155v1.pdf) on this topic
- Great [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125159/generalized-backpropagation-for-neural-networks-e-g-deepdream/133126#133126) explaining deep dreaming in Mathematica 11

Comment: oops, what is your trial...?

Comment: Do you think someone will help you implement that algorithm?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example from `NetTrain` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html) (Applications - Computer Vision - Style Transfer):

[image]

```
vggNet = NetModel["VGG-16 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
```

Take a subnet that will be used as a feature extractor for the style and content images:

```
featureNet = Take[vggNet, {1, "relu4_1"}]
```

[image]

There are three loss functions used. The first loss ensures that the "content" is similar in the synthesized image and the content image:

```
contentLoss = NetGraph[{MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort["LossContent"]}]
```

[image]

The second loss ensures that the "style" is similar in the synthesized image and the style image. Style similarity is defined as the mean-squared difference between the Gram matrices of the input and target:

```
gramMatrix = 
  NetGraph[{FlattenLayer[-1], TransposeLayer[1 -> 2], 
    DotLayer[]}, {1 -> 3, 1 -> 2 -> 3}];

styleLoss = NetGraph[{gramMatrix, gramMatrix, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]},
  {NetPort["Input"] -> 1, NetPort["Target"] -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, 
   3 -> NetPort["LossStyle"]}]
```

[image]

The third loss ensures that the magnitude of intensity changes across adjacent pixels in the synthesized image is small. This helps the synthesized image look more natural:

```
l2Loss = NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], 
    SummationLayer[]}, {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Target"]} -> 
     1 -> 2}];

tvLoss = NetGraph[<|
   "dx1" -> 
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}, "Padding" -> "Fixed" ],
   "dx2" -> 
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}, "Padding" -> "Fixed"],
   "dy1" -> 
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, "Padding" -> "Fixed" ],
   "dy2" -> 
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}}, "Padding" -> "Fixed"],
   "lossx" -> l2Loss, "lossy" -> l2Loss, "tot" -> TotalLayer[]|>, {
   {"dx1", "dx2"} -> "lossx", {"dy1", "dy2"} -> "lossy",
   {"lossx", "lossy"} -> "tot" -> NetPort["LossTV"]}]
```

[image]

Define a function that creates the final training net for any content and style image. This function also creates a random initial image:

```
createTransferNet[net_, content_Image, styleFeatSize_] := Module[
  {dims = Prepend[3]@Reverse@ImageDimensions[content]},
  NetGraph[<|
    "Image" -> 
     ConstantArrayLayer["Array" -> RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, dims]],
    "imageFeat" -> NetReplacePart[net, "Input" -> dims],
    "content" -> contentLoss,
    "style" -> styleLoss,
    "tv" -> tvLoss|>,
   {"Image" -> "imageFeat",
    {"imageFeat", NetPort["ContentFeature"]} -> "content",
    {"imageFeat", NetPort["StyleFeature"]} -> "style",
    "Image" -> "tv"},
   "StyleFeature" -> styleFeatSize
   ]
  ]
```

Define a `NetDecoder` for visualizing the predicted image:

```
meanIm = NetExtract[featureNet, "Input"][["MeanImage"]]
```

> {0.48502, 0.457957, 0.407604}

```
decoder = NetDecoder[{"Image", "MeanImage" -> meanIm}]
```

[image]

The training data consists of features extracted from the content and style images. Define a feature extraction function:

```
extractFeatures[img_] := 
  NetReplacePart[featureNet, 
    "Input" -> 
     NetEncoder[{"Image", ImageDimensions[img], 
       "MeanImage" -> meanIm}]][img];
```

Create a training set consisting of a single example of a content and style feature:

```
trainingdata = <|
   "ContentFeature" -> {extractFeatures[contentImg]}, 
   "StyleFeature" -> {extractFeatures[styleImg]}
   |>;
```

Create the training net whose input dimensions correspond to the content and style image dimensions:

```
net = createTransferNet[featureNet, contentImg, 
   Dimensions@First@trainingdata["StyleFeature"]];
```

When training, the three losses are weighted differently to set the relative importance of the content and style. These values might need to be changed with different content and style images. Create a loss specification that defines the final loss as a combination of the three losses:

```
perPixel = 1/(3*Apply[Times, ImageDimensions[contentImg]]);
lossSpec = {"LossContent" -> Scaled[6.*10^-5], 
   "LossStyle" -> Scaled[0.5*10^-14], 
   "LossTV" -> Scaled[20.*perPixel]};
```

Optimize the image using `NetTrain`. `LearningRateMultipliers` are used to freeze all parameters in the net except for the `ConstantArrayLayer`. The training is best done on a GPU, as it will take up to an hour to get good results with CPU training.

```
trainedNet = NetTrain[net,
  trainingdata, lossSpec,
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {"Image" -> 1, _ -> None},
  TrainingProgressReporting -> 
   Function[decoder[#Weights[{"Image", "Array"}]]],
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 300, BatchSize -> 1,
  Method -> {"ADAM", "InitialLearningRate" -> 0.05},
  TargetDevice -> "GPU"
  ]
```

[image]

```
decoder[NetExtract[trainedNet, {"Image", "Array"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *Mathematica **11.2*** has implemented this with the new function **ImageRestyle**.

---

Here is an example from Wolfram Blog:

[image: An example from Wolfram's Blog]

---

Another example:

[image: Another example input]
[image: Another example output]

---

You can refer to these for more details:

- [ImageRestyle—Wolfram Language Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRestyle.html)
- [It’s Another Impressive Release! Launching Version 11.2 Today—Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/09/14/its-another-impressive-release-launching-version-11-2-today/)