# Neural Nets: Can the back propagation/deep dream step be computed within the Net itself

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying see if I can do a deep dreaming algorithm without exiting a neural net.

This [Generalized Backpropagation for Neural Networks (e.g. DeepDream)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125159/generalized-backpropagation-for-neural-networks-e-g-deepdream/133126#133126) has a nice discussion of using the NetPortGradient to perform a gradient ascent on an image's pixel values (i.e., iteratively  "maximize the total amount of neuronal firing").  The gradient ascent is performed "outside of the net"--i.e., it uses a WL kernel functions (i.e., image += factor*gradient) on the output of a call to a trained net.

I know that there are two new resource functions to do deep dreams([deep dream alpha](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DeepDreamAlpha) and [deep dream beta](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DeepDreamBeta)), but I am trying to learn how to implement my own version.

Is it possible to forego the call and perform the entire operation within the net. In other words, can I modify the net to do the gradient ascent all by itself?

If yes, then a hint on how one would proceed would be appreciated.

Thank you